# Invalid postback or callback argument. in vs 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had developed an ASp.net Application in vs 2010.But due to some reasons I had to swtich t0 vs 2013.I had opened the same solution in vs 2013.When I click on the login butoon I get the abouve error, but when I run the same application in vs 2010 it works absolutely fine.
Please suggest me the possible solution.I dont want to use "enable Post validation in my application"

Comment: show us the relevant code and exception

Comment: solved had to add enbaleEventValidation ="false"